# How to prevent a click from opening another tab?

Tags: javascript, firefox

On some website everything looks fine until I click on a link (the link displayed in the lower left corner is normal as far as I can see and different from the one opened in another tab).

When I click however, sometime another tab is opened (and not the one I clicked on). Before the redirect I was able to copy the link:

```
javascript:window.opener=null;setTimeout(function(){window.location.href='http://papcontent.info/[...]'},250)
```

Can I prevent this javascript snippet from beeing executed without blocking the whole scripts with NoScript? The later does, unfortunately, render the website unusable.

The link that gets opened in the other tab is not the one I clicked on. It is not even in the source code of the webpage (neither in the generated one I got with the [Webdeveloper plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/web-developer/), nor the saved to disk one was the string "papc" or ".info" present).

The website is not mine and I prefer not to post the link unless it is really needed.

*I am not sure what details to put, so please ask questions and I'll add them.*

Comment: If we conclude that it is not the browser that injected the code (infected browser/extension) and that it is not in the site code, then there are only guesses. I think we are going to need the URL if you want an answer. Do not post the live link, but use the code formatting: ````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a "popunder."  They're essentially very rude pop-ups.  Some would go so far as to call them malicious.

To get around them, try this:

1. Chrome: Right click the link and choose "Copy link address" from the shortcut menu.

   IE: Right click the link, choose Properties, and copy the link address.
2. Open notepad and paste your clipboard there
3. Notepad should now contain the URL you want.  Visually inspect just to be sure.
4. Cut and paste the URL from notepad into your browser's address bar.

Comment: Popunder... nasty little things, especially if coupled with obfuscation. Thanks.